# Using D3.js + click events with Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a tree/hierarchy datastructure visualization using d3.js v4 in Angular. I essentially have just copied down this implementation https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd into a component, and have run into a problem with the 'click to expand/contract' feature. The visualization renders as expected on refresh, but when I click a node, I get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.update is not a function
Stack trace:
./src/app/components/data-displayer.component.ts/DataDisplayerComponent.prototype.click@http://localhost:4200/main.js:304:9
contextListener/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:69524:7
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2743:17
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:33761:24
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2742:17
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2510:28
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneTask.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2818:24
invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3862:9
globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3888:17
core.js:1598
```

It seems like when the onclick event is triggered, the subroutine (this.click) can't see the rest of the class anymore (I tried logging the class fields, which all were logged as undefined). It is still passed the correct data, it's just unable to call the `this.update` method. I'm using `angular: 6.0.1, Node: 8.9.1, OS: win32 x64`

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { HierarchyPointNode } from "d3";

export const margin = { top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120 };
export const width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left;
export const height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

@Component({
    selector: "data-displayer",
    template: "<svg></svg>",
    styleUrls: ["data-displayer.component.css"],
    providers: [],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class DataDisplayerComponent implements OnInit {
    private svg;
    private treeLayout;
    private root;

    ngOnInit() {
        d3.json("../../assets/flare.json").then(data => {

            this.root = d3.hierarchy(data, (d) => d.children);
            this.root.x0 = height / 2;
            this.root.y0 = 0;

            let collapse = function (d) {
                if (d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d._children.forEach(collapse);
                    d.children = null;
                }
            }    

            this.root.children.forEach(collapse);

            this.update(this.root);
        });

        this.svg = d3.select("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top                     + ")");

    this.treeLayout = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

}

update(source) {
    let i = 0;
    let duration = 750;

    let treeData = this.treeLayout(this.root);
    let nodes = treeData.descendants();
    let links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

    nodes.forEach(d => d.y = d.depth * 180);

    let node = this.svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, d =>  d.id || (d.id = ++i) );

    let nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", d => "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")")
        .on("click", this.click);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .style("fill", d => d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff");

    let nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

    nodeUpdate.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", d => "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")");

    nodeUpdate.select("circle.node")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("fill", d => d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff")
        .attr("cursor", "pointer");

    let nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", d => "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")")
        .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6);

    nodeExit.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

    let link = this.svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, d => d.id);

    let linkEnter = link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", d => {
            let o = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 };
            return this.diagonal(o, o);
        });

    let linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

    linkUpdate.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", d => {
            return this.diagonal(d, d.parent)
        });

    let linkExit = link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", d => {
            let o = { x: source.x, y: source.y };
            return this.diagonal(o, o);
        })
        .remove();

    nodes.forEach(d => {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });

}

click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }

    this.update(d);
}

diagonal(s, d) {
    let path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path;
}
```

Comment: `.on("click", this.click.bind(this));`

Comment: works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: This helped me a lot. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind `this` to the onclick method:

```
.on("click", this.click.bind(this));
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? This is the correct solution.